# How to take ownership of a Mutex of a tokio_postgres::Client with an async task?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, tokio-postgres

I want to create a function that returns a `tokio_postgres` client. However, I can't find a solution to take ownership of variable (a database connection from the library `tokio_postgres`) in an async task (to connect to the database).

Here is my code ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=63ea77e5ac290fcdb6f963922214cbcd)):

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use tokio_postgres::tls::NoTlsStream;
use tokio_postgres::{Client, Connection, Error, NoTls, Socket};

#[tokio::main] // By default, tokio_postgres uses the tokio crate as its runtime.
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let pg_client = create_pg_client("postgres://postgres:root@localhost:5432");
    // Use pg_client for the program
    Ok(())
}

//
// Creates a pg client
//
pub async fn create_pg_client(
    config: &str,
) -> Result<Arc<Mutex<(Client, Connection<Socket, NoTlsStream>)>>, Error> {
    // Connect to the database.
    let mut connect_result = Arc::new(Mutex::new(tokio_postgres::connect(config, NoTls).await?));

    let connect_result_thread = connect_result.clone();
    // The connection object performs the actual communication with the database,
    // so spawn it off to run on its own.
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let mut result = connect_result_thread.lock().unwrap();
        if let Err(e) = (&mut result.1).await {
            eprintln!("An error occured while trying to connect to the database");
        }
    });

    Ok(connect_result)
}
```

My code doesn't compile:

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src\pg_client.rs:18:5
    |
18  |     tokio::spawn(async move {
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ future created by async block is not `Send`
    | 
   ::: src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-1.5.0\src\task\spawn.rs:129:21
    |
129 |         T: Future + Send + 'static,
    |                     ---- required by this bound in `tokio::spawn`
    |
    = help: within `impl Future`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, (Client, tokio_postgres::Connection<Socket, NoTlsStream>)>`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
   --> src\pg_client.rs:20:25
    |
19  |         let mut result = connect_result_thread.lock().unwrap();
    |             ---------- has type `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, (Client, tokio_postgres::Connection<Socket, NoTlsStream>)>` which is not `Send`
20  |         if let Err(e) = (*result).1.await {
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ await occurs here, with `mut result` maybe used later
...
23  |     });
    |     - `mut result` is later dropped here
```

It says that future cannot be sent between threads safely. Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Crates used :

```
tokio = { version = "1.5.0", features = ["full"]}
tokio-postgres = "0.7.2"
```

Comment: You can't hold a lock across awaits. Try establishing the connection, before you put it inside the lock.

Comment: You can use a tokio mutex, whose guard can be sent across `await` points. For example, [this compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3c4929e382e7b7b703898cf17d274c98). But it's not really clear what the goal is here - if the connection is behind a mutex, you are effectively serializing its access from various tasks. Should it even be shared among tasks, then?

Comment: @user4815162342 Thank you for your answer, indeed it works with the `tokio` `Mutex`. After reading your message and some reflexion, using the `Connection` was a bad idea, I only had to return the `Client`, which doesn't requires any lock. If you want to add your anwser, I can mark it as the good answer :). Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library `Mutex` is designed to hold a lock within the context of a single thread. Since the task can be picked up by a different thread, values that cross `await` points must be `Send`. Additionally, even if it did work, using a blocking mutex in an async program is a bad idea because acquiring the mutex can take arbitrarily long, during which time other tasks cannot run on the same executor thread.

You can fix both issues by switching to [tokio's mutex](https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio/doc/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html) whose guard is `Send` and whose `lock()` method is async. For example, this compiles:

```
// Pick up an async aware Mutex
use tokio::sync::Mutex;

let connect_result = Arc::new(Mutex::new(tokio_postgres::connect(config, NoTls).await?));
let connect_result_thread = connect_result.clone();
tokio::spawn(async move {
    let mut result = connect_result_thread.lock().await;
    if let Err(e) = (&mut result.1).await {
        eprintln!("An error occured while trying to connect to the database: {}", e);
    }
});

Ok(connect_result)
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=26b4b2562173f47c0ccd22cb9580bc8d)

What remains unclear is the ultimate goal of this design. If the connection is behind a mutex, you are effectively serializing access to it from various tasks. Such a connection probably shouldn't be shared among tasks in the first place.

Comment: It's not generally a bad idea to use a blocking Mutex in an async program, this is a quote from the tokio `Mutex` docs: `If the data stored behind the mutex is just data, it is often better to use a blocking mutex such as the one in the standard library`. In this case it's a connection, so your advice is correct here.

Comment: @sebpuetz Agreed - some mutexes are held for only a very short while (e.g. those that just guard the update to a single number). But the answer tries to provide a zeroth-approximation advice to a beginner, and as such it makes sense. You are unlikely to do _wrong_ by always using an async mutex in async code, whereas you could do wrong by always using the stdlib one.